# Sending E-Mail from Redmine does not work, while sending via rake command does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, redmine, windows-server, bitnami

I encountered quite a strange behavior when setting up a new instance of Redmine 2.5.1 (Bitnami Stack) on a Windows server. I merely copied the functional E-Mail setup from another Redmine instance, it is roughly looking like the following

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "mail.mailhoster.de"
      port: 25
      domain: "bbb.de"
      authentication: :plain
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      user_name: "aaa@bbb.de"
      password: "123qwertz"
      openssl_verify_mode: none
```

(strings like addresses and passwords are anonymized)

Like I said, the very setup is working perfectly on another server (Linux though). Also, if I am running the rake task to send a test E-Mail, it works flawlessly. But whenever I am trying to send an E-Mail via the web interface - be it a notification, be it a test E-Mail - it does not work. The test E-Mail gives me an

```
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed
```

error. I did check the setup several times, but it is correct and working on the Linux machine. Furthermore I checked the RAILS_ENV, but it's production both for the rake task and for the real app.

I tried enabling E-Mail logging, but the only thing production.log gives me is

```
Started GET "/redmine/admin/test_email" for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX at 2014-05-28 08:24:14 +0200
Processing by AdminController#test_email as HTML
  Current user: XXXX (id=1)
  Rendered mailer/test_email.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
  Rendered mailer/test_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.0ms)
Redirected to http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/redmine/settings?tab=notifications
```

Are there any peculiarities of the Bitnami Redmine Stack I'll have to consider? Is it any more than Apache I'll have to allow in the firewall configuration?

It's not very critical - for the time being it'll be sufficient having Redmine to work without E-Mail notifications - but it really makes my head ache, for I don't get why it couldn't work out. I'd be very grateful, if someone could help me.

Comment: For some strange reason it's working now without having edited the configuration file. Seems to be some strange interaction with the SMTP...

Answer (score 0):

This is and old thread, but I had the same problem and the solution was ensuring that the my Redmine email delivery configuration was on  **"config/configuration.yml"**, deleting the double quotes on address, domain, user_name, password and finally (the most important), disabling async_smtp by using just the smtp delivery method. Maybe sending the email on a different thread on the rake task could have the same effect.

Hope it helps...

Comment: For me this is not relevant anymore (and I'm not able to check), but I hope that this will help anyone else.